# how to create a tag on source code hosted in code.google.com?

Tags: svn, google-code

I have hosted my code on code.google.com. I selected subversion as the repository to be used and have checked-in all my code. I am trying to create a tag on the repository and I am unable to find any straightforward way to do this. Can someone please guide me as to what needs to be done to create a tag? Do I use some subversion command? Or is there something available in the UI in code.google.com to do this which I am overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion supports tags only by convention. You should make a copy (`svn cp`) of your `trunk` branch to `tags/foo` and that's it. There is no special command.

So, for example:

```
svn cp https://PROJECT.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ https://PROJECT.googlecode.com/svn/tags/TAG/
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're not supposed to do this through the web interface, but using your subversion client. In subversion, creating a tag is exactly the same operation as making a copy of your trunk folder into a folder called tags. Same goes for 'branche'. So you'll probably do something like:

```
svn copy yourtrunkUrl tags/tagname
```